# Angularjs nested router does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angular route and have some problems when using nested one:

The following 'abc' state works perfectly for route /admin/team/:teamId

```
.state('admin', {
    url: '/admin',
    controller: 'AdminController',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/index.html'
})
.state('admin.home', {
    url: '/home',
    parent: 'admin',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/dashboard.html'
})
.state('admin.team', {
    url: '/team',
    parent: 'admin',
    controller: 'TeamController',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/team/index.html'
})
.state('abc', {
    url: '/admin/team/:teamId',
    // parent: 'admin.team',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        console.info('$stateParams.teamId', $stateParams.teamId);
    },
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/player/index.html'
});
```

but if I replace the state 'abc' as the following, the player template does not render and hold onto the admin/team/index.html, even no console output, such as:

```
.state('admin.team.details', {
    url: '/:teamId',
    parent: 'admin.team',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        console.info('$stateParams.teamId', $stateParams.teamId);
    },
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/player/index.html'
});
```

are there anyway for me to solve it?

Comment: Do you have a `ui-view` inside your `/views/admin/team/index.html` file?

Comment: have. it works perfect for reoute admin.team state. I just want to add the function for team details with rendering whole new template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally, I've found the following would works:

```
.state('admin.team', {
    url: '/team',
    parent: 'admin',
    controller: 'TeamController',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/team/index.html'
})
.state('admin.team.details', {
    url: '/team/:teamId',
    parent: 'admin',
    controller: 'PlayerController',
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/player/index.html'
});
```

Thanks for all answering me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.state('admin.team.details', {
    url: '/details/:teamId',
    parent: 'admin.team',
    controller: function($scope, $stateParams){
        console.info('$stateParams.teamId', $stateParams.teamId);
    },
    templateUrl: '/views/admin/player/index.html'
});
```

Comment: same result...the route is catched but it stills get hold in team page...or any other ways for me to do the same things?

Comment: Can you remove the parent attribute from the state defs? I normally do not use that attribute.

Comment: Or can you paste the code where/how the state is being invoked?

Comment: Can you show the code for /views/admin/team/index.html and /views/admin/player/index.html ?